# Filezilla and Notepad++

Tags: windows-8, ftp, notepad++, filezilla

I'm trying to "Edit" a file from my Filzilla FTP and it opens in Notepad++ just fine, but when it opens it prompts me:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\-open doesn't exist. Create it?`

>Yes

`Cannot create the file "C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\-open"`

Do I not have permissions for this to auto-create the temporary file? How do I check? What are some other things I could check to figure out why this isn't working correctly?

I'm running Windows 8 and the latest versions of both Notepad++ and Filezilla.

Comment: try running filezilla with "run as administrator". An application should not open temp files in the Program Files folder. Usually: C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: In your FileZilla settings what do you have for 'File Editing' Settings?

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client-open"

**-open** it is not a valid argument:

In FileZilla settings try for example just:

```
html "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

without the "-open" argument.
*http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches*